# When does the achievement pop-up appear?

Tags: support, achievements-dialog, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm not sure what keyboard combo I clicked, but the end result was this

[image]

How do you make this happen?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You had keyboard shortcuts enabled in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current)

[image]

Pressing `r` will activate the achievements popup you saw.

There are a lot more shortcuts available. Once enabled, then press `?` on every page and try them out.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know these existed. Really handy - maybe worth making more discoverable?

Comment: @SteveBennett feel free to create a feature-request on MSE

Comment: Can't say I have a lot of faith in feature requests around here.

Comment: [Why not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-completed)? (Excluding any H&I queues) @SteveBennett

Comment: I think answering that question would be off-topic here.